# How to hyperlink the character in paragraph which coming in Json data

Tags: html, json

**Problem Statement :**

I am getting a `JSON` data with Paragraph and LinkLocation(location for hiperlink the characters in the paragraph using LinkLocation:(6,12)). It means, character 6 to character 12 in the paragraph we need to hyperlink and redirect that to another page. Please advice me how to do that.

```
link:{id: 3, index: "Law 1.1", name: "Number of Players ",…}
content:"Law 1.1 shall be replaced by the following."
description:"Law 1.1 shall be replaced by the following:"
id:3
index:"Law 1.1"
ischanged:false
iscollapsed:false
islinked:false
isread:false
linkid:0
linktype:0
name:"Number of Players "
linkposition:"1, 6"
```

This is my JSON data. from this data i want to hyperlink the "content" paragraph as per the "Linkposition". for example here the link position is "1,6". so i want to hyperlink the "Law 1.1" in the content Paragraph.

Comment: so is it like:

data -> {paragraph: hello there, link:1-4}

and you want send to another page:

data -> {paragraph: h<a href='other.page'>ell</a>o there}  ?

Comment: If the paragraph is like "Hello world" and the link data is 1,5, then "Hello" should be hyperlinked and i have to give link there where should i redirect that.

Comment: include this example in your question... it helps in understanding...

Comment: link:{id: 3, index: "Law 1.1", name: "Number of Players ",…}
content:"Law 1.1 shall be replaced by the following."
description:"Law 1.1 shall be replaced by the following:"
id:3
index:"Law 1.1"
ischanged:false
iscollapsed:false
islinked:false
isread:false
linkid:0
linktype:0
name:"Number of Players "
linkposition:"1, 6".      This is my Json data. in this i want to hyperlink the content paragraph as per the linkposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hyperlink a subset of characters in a string you can do it this way:

```
var data = {
  paragraph: "hello world",
  link: '1,5'
}

var limits = link.split(',');

//subtract one cos substring method is inclusive of bottom limit and exclusive of upper limit
var lowerLimit = limits[0]-1;
var upperLimit = limits[1];

var newParagraph = data.paragraph.substr(0, lowerLimit) + "<a href='otherpage.html'>" + data.paragraph.substr(lowerLimit, upperLimit) + "</a>" + data.paragraph.substr(upperLimit, data.parapgraph.length);
```

So that would produce the result

```
<a href='otherpage.html'>Hello</a> world
```

Hence 'Hello' is hyperlinked

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... I have added a function `addLinksToParagraph(paragraph, linkLocation, location)` which might help you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var jsonData = {
            paragraph : 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.',
            linkLocation : '1,6',
        }

        $('p').html(addLinksToParagraph(jsonData.paragraph, jsonData.linkLocation, "/any_location.html"));

        function addLinksToParagraph(paragraph, linkLocation, location) {

            var splitArray = linkLocation.split(',');

            var start = parseInt(splitArray[0]);
            var end = parseInt(splitArray[1]);

            var preLink = paragraph.substr(0, start);  //part before the hyperlink part
            var link = paragraph.substr(start, end);   //the actual hyperlink part
            var postLink = paragraph.substr(end + 1);  //part after hyperlink part

            console.log(preLink);
            console.log(link);
            console.log(postLink);

            return preLink + '<a href="' + location +'">' + link + '</a>' + postLink;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will produce following output.

[image]